# SqlPackage not exporting entire database

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, sql-server-data-tools

I'm trying to move a fairly large database (50GB) to Azure. I am running this command on the local Sql Server to generate a bacpac I can upload.

SqlPackage.exe /a:Export /ssn:localhost /sdn:MDBILLING /su:sa /sp:SomePassword /tf:"D:\test.bacpac"

The export does not print any errors and finishes with "Successfully exported database and saved it to file 'D:\test.bacpac'."

When I look at the bacpac in the file system, it always comes out to be 3.7GB. There's no way a 50GB database can be compressed that small. I upload it to Azure regardless. The package upload succeeds, but when I query the Azure database most of the tables return 0 rows. It's almost as if the bacpac does not contain all my database's data.

Are there any known limitations with this export method? Database size, certain data types, etc?

I tried using the 64bit version of SqlPackage reading that some experienced out of memory issues on large databases, but I wasn't getting this error or any error for that matter.

**UPDATE/EDIT:** I made some progress after ensuring that the export is transactionally consistent by restoring a backup and then extracting a bacpac from that. However, now I have run into a new error when uploading to Azure.

I receive the following message (using S3 database):

*Error encountered during the service operation. Data plan execution failed with message One or more errors occurred. One or more errors occurred. One or more errors occurred. One or more errors occurred. XML parsing: Document parsing required too much memory One or more errors occurred. XML parsing: Document parsing required too much memory*

Comment: Which version of SQLPackage are you running? Have you grabbed the May 2015 update to DacFX?

Comment: The digital signature on SqlPackage.exe is dated ‎Thursday, ‎February ‎19, ‎2015 4:02:17 PM. Where else could I check?

Comment: Looks like that is the February update, try out the May one from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46898

Comment: My Google searching appears to be inferior. I'll give this a try, thanks!

Comment: I was able to verify all the table data was in the bacpac; you can open any bacpac using a zip utility. Microsoft thinks that because I'm leaving the database "live" while exporting the bacpac, that it's not transactionally consistent. So while Azure is unpacking the data, a foreign key insert fails and the rest of the import terminates. I am going to restore a backup and make a bacpac out of this. I'll post my findings.

Comment: That is true, bacpac operations are not transactionally consistent. The best workaround/test for that is to create a copy of your database and create a bacpac of it.

Comment: Change your "storage" method via /p:Storage={File|Memory} Change it to File and you shouldn't get that issue from your new error.

Comment: The Storage flag did not help. It still fails with the same error. I do see there's a table in the database called [_TransactionIndex_d86ded29-6318-49e4-be27-eb0677fe6cd1]. It has 1259 GUIDs in it. Its contents don't mean much to me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is resolved. My issues were two-fold.

First, because bacpac operations are not transactionally consistent, I had to restore from backup and make a bacpac out of the restored database. This ensured users were not adding rows while the bacpac was being generated.

Second issue was an XML column in my database. The table has roughly 17 million rows and of those rows roughly 250 them had really large xml documents stored in them (200000+ characters). Removing those 250 rows and them reimporting solved my problems. I really don't think it was the size of the xml document that Azure had an issue with. I think those large documents contained special characters the xml parser didn't like.

It's unclear to me how Sql Server allows unparseable xml to get into my database in the first place, but that was the other issue.